# Why Prettier code formatter stopped formatting in VS Code?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, code-formatting, prettier

I am trying to format the code but the prettier isn't working fine with VS code. I also tried to reinstall it but the same problem occurs. I am not able to format my html css code with prettier. You can also see the screenshot where the code is not formatted after saving the code.

[image]

Comment: This can help i think- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/code-formatting-with-prettier-in-visual-studio-code

it needs to be configured properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps carefully, and I think it is gonna work. First, make sure you install Prettier from the extensions store:

[image]

Then edit the `settings.json` file and paste in it the lines below. You can find `settings.json` this way:

- On Windows: `F1` or `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `P`, then type `open settings` and choose `Open Settings (JSON)`
- On MacOS: `Shift` + `CMD` + `P`, then the same steps as Windows

```json
{ 

  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  
}
```

And finally, restart VS Code.

Answer (score 2):

Edit settings.json page

- Windows: Ctrl + Shift + P
- On MacOS: Shift + CMD + P

I had to add the following:

```
{
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[jsonc]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[json]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[css]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "[scss]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you apply the steps mentioned in the below answer (by Youssouf Oumar) , and still got no solution, then there may be an error that prettier is catching. You can always check for that by clicking on the bottom right corner, where it says prettier (tho if there are two small check marks, then there's probably no errors at all)